# Is there a default http body size limit set by iis8, and if so, what is it?

Tags: iis-8

Is there a limit, and if so what is it? The following page:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/limits

explains the following:

the maxRequestEntityAllowed attribute specifies the maximum number of bytes allowed in the entity body of an ASP request. If a Content-Length header is present and specifies an amount of data greater than the value of maxRequestEntityAllowed, IIS returns an HTTP 403 error response.

I'm not sure where I would find this attribute or if there's a standard default value I can usually expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, the configuration attribute you describe is not a general IIS setting. It is for classic ASP only and affects the size of the request body, or the amount of data you can send in a POST when submitting a form.

It has nothing to do with the size of the body in an html page.

The default setting for this is `200000 bytes` as you can see in the UI under

```
ASP - Limit Properties - Maximum Requesting Entity Body Limit
```

When using IIS PowerShell cmdlets you can use:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "system.webServer/asp/limits" -name "maxRequestEntityAllowed"
```

to find that value.

Comment: Hi For the life of me, I cannot see the ASP icon in ISS 8 on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: This Q/A may be of interest - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/is-http-post-limitless   Not calling it a dupe, but very related.  I don't do IIS (or Windows) but you may end up at protocol or specific client limits on your journey to server-side limits.